# WhatsApp and other main apps not showing

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, lumia-540

I'm using Microsoft Lumia 540. Around 4 hrs ago my phone got switched off due to low battery but after switching it on I can't see most of the apps. All the apps which were in the start screen are gone and are also gone from the more apps window. Even the call/ message is not visible.
Did anyone of you face a similar issue?? Please help.

Also, when a WhatsApp message arrives - it shows on my notification but no action on clicking it and it's(the notification's) heading is not **WhatsApp** instead it shows some other random numbers and alphabets. It shows similar behavior when a text message arrives.
Please help

Comment: No dear this problem is with you only . Take your phone at repairing lab

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @M.JunaidRehman. I did a hard reset.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked so I had to hard reset it. The problem is gone. All apps are working fine now.