# Start screen completely empty

Tags: windows-10-mobile

Something really weird since yesterday: 
- The start screen is completely blank
- just a search box at the top
- no tiles at all
- swipe left does nothing

Incoming calls, messages and whatsapps are received and appear in the notification zone, but without display texts for associated applications:
[image]

Clicking on the WhatsApp notification will open WhatsApp and from there it is possible to reply. Clicking on the text message does nothing, and the inline answering function shows, but send doesn't appear to do anything.

Using the search function in the (empty) start screen, I can click through to "search in Store", and the store will recognise that WhatsApp is installed, and from there I can launch it. But that's no help for the built-in Windows applications.

I'm wondering whether this is related to a recent update:
[image]

What I've tried:
- Soft resets
- Changing display language/region
- Freeing some disk space (the SD card was full, but not the phone)

My questions:
- Has anyone seen anything similar?
- Is there any way to work out *when* an update was installed?
- Is there any way to rollback to a previous update?
- Is there anything else you can think of, short of hard reset?

(Possibly related, but not encouraging: [WhatsApp and other main apps not showing](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16826/whatsapp-and-other-main-apps-not-showing))

Comment: The irony of searching for "Windows phones no applications" kills me ...

Comment: We will never no, I ended up doing a hard reset. Apparently one of my kids was messing with the phone when it happened. No idea what they did though...